# Chess piece hierarchy design: inheritance vs type fields

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, chess

I have a base class for pieces

```
 class piece;
```

and an array containing derived objects

```
piece* board[8][8];
```

Advantage, clean design through virtual functions. Disadvantage, if I have to find a piece in the board or compare a piece I have to revert to dynamic casting (or typeid). It’s ugly and could be a performance hog when making millions of requests.

In the other hand, if I make an array of a single piece class, that has a type field for identifying pieces, I don’t have this problem (and it should be faster) but I have to make super ugly switch statements. I guess that since the number of pieces is finite and I don’t see myself making that many of switches, this could be in the end a better choice, what do you think?

This is for fun (so no bitboard).

Reading some answers, I think using type fields only for operator overloading (`==`, `!=`, ...) could bring the best of both words.

The `boost::variant` looks very interesting too.

Comment: Using type field and switch is the wrong way to go. You will just make the code a complete mess to read an maintain. Stick with OO principles they do actually work.

Comment: After reading the answers below I am not sure how you reached that conclusion they all seem to suggest (the ones with votes) using the OO approach.

Comment: Yes there's an overwhelming vote of confidence for inheritance, and I'm not going against that, I'm just thinking that using the type field 'only' for piece equality or traversing the board array might be more efficient that dynamic_casting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with the class hierarchy.

For finding a piece you can keep a separeted list for each piece type. So you know where to look for each piece type.

For comparison you can rely on virtual methods too.

Another aproach is to use a component architecture (like described here: http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/), but I think it is too much for a chess game where you clealy know the types and know that those types will not change soon :).

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, if your set of classes is limited - i.e. you know the number, use a variant and visitors. For example, `boost::variant<king, queen, bishop, knight ...>` And the board is made up of a 2D array of this type. Now to interrogate, you can use visitors...

Comment: +1, very clean. Also, you don't have the virtual dispatch overhead, useful when crawling billions of positions. This will probably compile as a switch case, but without the ugliness.

Comment: and a switch is faster than a virtual function because ... ?

Comment: @wilhelmtell, because of the branch predictor? (in some cases)

Comment: @7vies a virtual function call costs a single dereference. Again: how is a switch cheaper than a virtual function call?

Comment: @wilhelmtell, what do you mean by "a single dereference"? For me, a virtual function call is asm's `call` with a dynamic parameter, implying at least saving registers and doing a `jmp` to a dynamic location. Except when this can be optimized by the compiler, which does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: @7vies: Presumable at the switch point (for any non trivial code) a function is called (otherwise you are putting all the code into same function. So a switch is a jmp followed by a function call. Any arguent that a virutal function call is slower than a normal function is hogswash (apart from in a vary very tight loop). In all other situations the extra cost of the virtual dispatch is trivial compared to all the other things that are going to cause the processor to stall.

Comment: @Martin, you can have some very simple logic under the switch too, and in this case impact of a function call might become important (though, I agree that this probably not the most common case). Also, a normal function call can be inlined then it won't be a function call anymore.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: We're talking about nano-optimizations here, but I think for a virtual method call two pointers have to be dereferenced: one to the object and one to the virtual method pointer table; the jump goes to the address stored in that table; which might count as another dereference.

Comment: @Martin: To clarify, I completely agree that in most cases function call overhead is negligible. I just wanted to clarify that there *is* still a difference, even if it is small.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the hierarchy and if I want to know the type (why?) have a virtual method which identifies the type.

Comment: For example, I would like to verify that there’s no white pawn on board[0][0], so that I can place another white piece at this location. Right now I’m doing a comparison through a template that contains a dynamic_cast .

Comment: @joey_89: I would suggest having another data structure in addition to the board that holds the pieces so you can check this for certain constraints about the pieces (like side[white].haveAllPawnsBeenTaked())

Comment: I replaced the board array with an unordered_map<int,piece_type> to make easy position lookup.

Answer (score 1):

I never wrote a chess program, but I'd guess the most common operations would be things like:

- display/print the board
- get the set of possible moves for each piece
- sum up the values of all pieces for a board, maybe sum up some kind of "position value" that depends on the piece (rook on an open line, things like that)

Additionally, some of the pieces have "state" (a king can only castle if it hasn't moved before, a pawn can strike in passing if the other pawn just moved two squares) that only apply to one kind of piece.

That all screams class hierarchy to me. (Assuming you don't need bitboard-performance)

On the other hand, it's unlikely that you will ever have to add new piece types or that you will ever be able to re-use one of the piece types in separation. i.e. extensibility and modularity is not really an issue. So if you find that some important part of your algorithm that should really be in one place is scattered over multiple piece classes - use a switch statement. Just add an abstract method tp the `Piece` class that returns a `PieceType` enum and switch on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't worry about performance and code for fun at the same time :)

Consider having "nibbleboard" (or at least byteboard) instead of bitboard, where each nibble represents one piece type. Each nibble is also index in the table of singleton objects that operate on that piece type.

```
class Empty : public Piece {};
class Rook : public Piece {};
...

const int wrook = 1;
...
const int bpawn = 12;

Piece* Operator[13] = {new Empty(), new Rook(), ..., new Pawn()};

byte table[64] = {
    wrook, wbishop, wknight, wking, wqueen, wknight, wbishop, wrook,
    wpawn, wpawn, wpawn, wpawn, wpawn, wpawn, wpawn, wpawn, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    bpawn, bpawn, bpawn, bpawn, bpawn, bpawn, bpawn, bpawn, 
    brook, bbishop, bknight, bking, bqueen, bknight, bbishop, brook};

// Given some position and some operation DoSomething we would have this:
Operator[table[position]]->DoSomething(table, position, <other parameters>);

// Possible return value of DoSomething might be new table
```

Comment: "You can't worry about performance and code for fun at the same time :)" Touché

Answer (score 0):

The "super ugly switch statement" is the **correct technique**. It isn't ugly. It's called functional programming.

Inheritance is completely the wrong technique. Each of the pieces moves in a different way, has a different graphic, and other properties. There's nothing common. Chess pieces are not abstract. They're a concrete collection of discrete objects.

You have to make something common by unification: creating what is called a sum type.
In Ocaml:

```
type shape = Pawn | Rook | Knight | Bishop | Queen | King
type color = Black | White
type piece = shape * color
type pos = { row:int;  col:int }

let check_white_move piece board from to = match piece with
| Pawn -> on_board to && (from.row = 2 && to.row = 4 or to.row = from.row + 1)
| ....
```

In C++ there is no proper sum type, you can use instead:

```
enum shape { pawn, rook, knight, bishop, queen, king};
..
bool check_white_move (..) { switch piece {
 case pawn: ...
```

It's more clumsy. Complain to the C and C++ committees. But use the right concept. Sum types (discriminated unions, variants) are *the* way to unify a discrete set of concrete types. Classes and inheritance are used for representing abstractions and providing implementations thereof.

There's nothing abstract about chess. It's all about combinations. This is not a question of advantages and disadvantages of different techniques: it's about using the correct technique.

[BTW: yea, you can try boost variant though I can't recommend it for this application since the pieces have no associated data an enum is perfect]

Comment: Having written a chess program in C++ I must totally disagree. All pieces are a concrete representation of an abstract piece. All pieces have the same properties (ie they move()/they display())

Comment: Actually, the pieces have associated data. The positions of the pieces of the board is not a complete description of the state of the game at any time (think passing strike, castling!)

Comment: "Chess pieces are not abstract": This sounds like a strange interpretation of OOP: usually, a class represents something abstract (like the idea/concept of a person or a rook in a platonic sense). The instance of a class typically represents something concrete, like John Smith over there or the left knight on my chessboard with the missing ear. That way, pawn, rook, knight are perfect candidates for classes, with "chess piece" being the superclass, because they all fall under that class by virtue of being a pawn, rook or knight.